# Is there a method to get all status bar items?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In an extension I would like to iterate over all items in the status bar. Can this be done?

The documentation seems to give the statusBarItem object, but no object for the bar itself.

If I have two modules, the only way I found to pass a new item I created is to define a getter for it. Is that the only way?

Comment: There isn't any way to get other status bar items. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @RobLourens testing